# Oracle dynamic run error

Tags: oracle

I created a procedure with dynamic sql,but cannot run it successfully.

```
create or replace procedure getdata(string par1, results out cursor)
as
declare sqlBase varchar2(100);
begin
    sqlBase := 'open '||results|| ' for select * from studetns';
end;
```

After running, the following error message pops up:

> PLS-00306, wrong number or types of arguments in call to  '||'

I just need to filter data by some parameters ,but some parameters may be null or empty,
so I need to filter dynamic. like if(par1 is not null) then ........
so here I need to use dynamic sql. in C# programe, use cursor to return result.
like here ,I use cursor type to open select statements.

but in sql editor, I get right sql statement.

Can Somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a little bit wrong. Try with this:

```
create or replace procedure getdata(par1 varchar2, par2 varchar2, results out sys_refcursor)
as
begin
   open results for
      select *
      from   students
      where  name = nvl(par1, name)
      and    surname = nvl(par2, surname);
end;
```

Why do you need parameter `par1`? Better to use PL/SQL type `varchar2`, not `string`. They work the same, but `varchar2` is a base data type, while `string` is a subtype of it.

Comment: You are right, thanks for that. `string` is the same as `varchar2`.

Comment: I need to use par to filter data. there are more than one parameters. here ,I just list one parameter. use cursor to return select result.

Comment: Then just add `where name = par1` to the select statement.

Comment: but the par1 maybe is null, then I don't need to use it to filter. if have par2 is not null ,then use par2 to filter, then have par3, par4.......

Comment: I edited the answer to include par2 and the logic if the parameter can be null. If you have more parameters, just add them in the procedure header and in the select statement.

Comment: Nvl(par,name) if par is not null then equal where name =par1, but if par1 is null ,then equal to what? where name =@name ? @name should be what's value?

Comment: That's a little trick. If `par1` is null, then `name=name` and `par1` has no effect on the select.

Comment: Haha, this way can work partially . now, I have a date to filter, like

Comment: Haha, this way can work partially . now, I have a date to filter, like  date between nvl(par1, date) and nvl(par2,date),this is cannot work. have some ways to satisfy this ? thanks very much

Comment: Yes, your solution is totally ok, it's my question,then ,if i want to pass date value from c# code to store procedure. how to pass null date ,or datetime.minimun value.?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, I would try something like that:

```
create or replace procedure getdata(par1 varchar2, results out sys_refcursor)
as

sqlBase varchar2(100);

begin
    sqlBase := 'begin open :X for select * from students;end;';
    execute immediate sqlbase USING IN OUT results;
end;
```

You can't concatenate a cursor into a string as you tried it, that's where your error came from.

But if you could clearify your question we could help you better.

Comment: I just want to use some paramters to filter data, but the parameters is option  to select ,if par1 is null ,then don't use it to filter.if par2 is not null,then use par2, then the same as par3, par4, par5 .....

Comment: Ok, I think you don't need dynamic SQL. Just use the answer of @AlenOblak

Comment: Yes. Now, I thinks @AlenOblak solution is OK, thanks